# How to make lines styles with offset join properly?

Tags: qgis, style

I want to draw the lanes of a two-lane street in different colors. I tried to apply an offset to a symbol layer which works fine for a single line but the ends of two connected lines do not join properly. Depending on the angle, the lines overlap or there is a gap between the lines.

Is there any way to solve my use case?